# Returning data to access outside of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a function that accepts a channel as a parameter.

The function takes the parameter and searches for the channel in mongodb. I need to return the data so that I can access it outside of the function.

I know what I'm doing wrong, the problem is I don't know how to fix it, and after spending the last 3 hours trying to do so I've given up and came here.

Here's the code:

```
var getStream = function(channel) {
    Stream.find({'channel': channel}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
    // How do I return this data??
    });
};

console.log(getStream('summit5g')); <-- undefined
```

Comment: `find` is asynchronous. Use `Promise` or `Callback`. Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kh7da9wv/

Comment: ahh, this is exactly what I need. Thank you Rayon!